# In Rails filter all ActiveRecord calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a rail app which is meant for users from different Organizations.

I want to make a mechanism that will make sure that when a user gets any data from the db, it can be only from his organization.

I want that to be true even if there is a bug in my queries i.e. I want this filter to be independent of all other code.

How can I implement this filter to run on all ActiveRecord calls?

can I use "default_scope" (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods/default_scope) for that but apply it to all models some how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For me the only way to achieve that properly is by scoping all your methods to something like

```
user_organization.<relation>.<query>
```

You can for example have a user_organization method in your ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def user_organization
    current_user.organization
  end
end
```

The default scope does not accept parameters if I'm not wrong, and I highly discourage you using for anything.

Comment: I agree that this would be a nice way, but my goal is to make sure a bug CANNOT happen if someone makes a mistake in the query in any case.